# Will the Move ctor effective in all scenarios?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I just came across the below code from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293665.aspx that shows how to implement move ctor:

```
MemoryBlock(MemoryBlock&& other)
   : _data(nullptr)
   , _length(0)
{
   std::cout << "In MemoryBlock(MemoryBlock&&). length = " 
             << other._length << ". Moving resource." << std::endl;

   // Copy the data pointer and its length from the 
   // source object.
   _data = other._data;
   _length = other._length;

   // Release the data pointer from the source object so that
   // the destructor does not free the memory multiple times.
   other._data = nullptr;
   other._length = 0;
}
```

here one of the question/doubt that came along with this code is: if the class `MemoryBlock` contains some class type member variable (say `someclassvar` ), and if that member is considerably huge, will the below line in the modified move ctor be effective (assumed that this `someclassvar` doesn't have move ctor)?

```
MemoryBlock(MemoryBlock&& other)
   : _data(nullptr)
   , _length(0),someclassvar(other.someclassvar)
{
   std::cout << "In MemoryBlock(MemoryBlock&&). length = " 
             << other._length << ". Moving resource." << std::endl;

   // Copy the data pointer and its length from the 
   // source object.
   _data = other._data;
   _length = other._length;
  // someclassvar=other.someclassvar;

   // Release the data pointer from the source object so that
   // the destructor does not free the memory multiple times.
   other._data = nullptr;
   other._length = 0;
   delete other.someclassvar;
}
```

here `someclassvar = other.someclassvar;` I believe this would call the copy assignment operator, so is this behavior effective? And also, if `someclassvar` contained both move assignment and copy assignment, which could be expected to call?

Will the move ctor remain be effective in all cases like this? If not, is having the copy ctor better?

Comment: `someclassvar = std::move(other.someclassvar);`

Comment: `(assumed that this someclassvar doesn't have move ctor)` has std::move do the job?

Comment: No. `std::move` will `move` if `move ctor / move =` is available else `copy`

Comment: first of all Move doesn't actually move, it just unconditionally casts the argument to rvalue which move ctor will accept, my question will the move ctor i constructed will be efficient in all cases?

Comment: As you show it `someclassvar` is (probably) some pointer, thus the line in question will be a pointer assignment.

Comment: Dany ,well caught !i changed it to non pointer type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of, in any constructor if possible you should prefer to initialize your members in the constructor's initializer list. Secondly, in a move constructor you should use `std::move` to either move the members that are moveable or copy them if they are unmovable:

```
MemoryBlock(MemoryBlock&& other)
: _data(std::move(other._data)), 
  _length(std::move(other._length)),
  someclassvar(std::move(other._someclassvar)) {
   // optionally set state of moved object
}
```

Now `std::move` doesn't move any objects but rather cast them to rvalue reference. Consequently and due to overload resolution two things are going to happen:

1. If the type to be moved has a user defined or an implicit defined move constructor, this move constructor is going to be evoked and thus, the object is going to be moved accordingly to its new host.
2. If the type to be moved hasn't got any defined move constructor then the copy constructor of that type is going to be evoked. This is attributed to the fact that rvalue references can bind to `const` lvalue references and thus with the luck of move constructor the copy constructor is a match for overload resolution.

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7183d944b7815500)

Now more or less the same goes for copy assignment and move assignment. Doing:

```
someclassvar = other.someclassvar;
```

will copy assign `other.someclassvar` to `someclassvar`. Why? due to overload resolution rules. However, if you do:

```
someclassvar = std::move(other.someclassvar);
```

If `someclassvar` has a move assignment operator then for the same reasons as explained above it's going to be evoked. On the other hand, if `someclassvar` doesn't have a move assignment operator, its assignment operator is going to be evoked. No constructors are involved here because the statement is an assignment.

Comment: nice..i just copied the code, but i will go with the initializer list as you said.

Answer (score 1):

```
MemoryBlock(MemoryBlock&& other)
   : _data(nullptr)
   , _length(0), someclassvar(std::move(other.someclassvar))
{
   std::cout << "In MemoryBlock(MemoryBlock&&). length = " 
             << other._length << ". Moving resource." << std::endl;

   // Copy the data pointer and its length from the 
   // source object.
   _data = other._data;
   _length = other._length;

   // Release the data pointer from the source object so that
   // the destructor does not free the memory multiple times.
   other._data = nullptr;
   other._length = 0;
}
```

If `someclassvar` class have `move ctor/ move =` then `std::move(other.someclassvar)` will `move` else it will `copy`.

If it needs to be efficient provide  `move ctor/ move =` for the class `someclassvar`.

Comment: will having copy ctor/ assigment in the above case result the same as having move ctor/assignment?